# WordPress Mailerlite - How to include mailerlite SDK in plugin

Tags: plugins

I'm trying to create a plugin such that whenever the user registers he automatically gets added to mailerlite group

but I'm getting an error after including the mailerlite sdk such that the class doesn't exist. You can find my code and the error here

https://github.com/asamolion/mailerlite-auto-signup

I just can't seem to find out how to include the API in the plugin.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is really PHP issue, not specifically WP - the class is [namespaced](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php), so you need:

```
$mailerlite = new MailerLiteApi\MailerLite;
```